# Adobe Photoshop Scripting - How to Select Bounding Box Around Current Selection?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Does anyone know whether it's possible, in Photoshop extend script, to convert an irregular selection (e.g. magic wand tool selection) into a rectangular selection encompassing the top, left, bottom and right bounds of the selection?

Comment: Only if it's on a layer of it's own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is, I have documented the code so you can modify it later if you need. Also, check page 166 and following of Photoshop's JS reference manual, you may read more about selections - you can set feather, extend/intersect/etc. the selection if you need to.

Made for CS6, should work with latter.

```
#target photoshop
if (documents.length == 0) {
    alert("nothing opened");
} else {
    // start

    //setup
    var file = app.activeDocument;
    var selec =  file.selection; 

    //run
    var bnds = selec.bounds; // get the bounds of current selection
    var // save the particular pixel values
       xLeft = bnds[0],
       yTop = bnds[1],
       xRight = bnds[2],
       yBottom = bnds[3];

    var newRect = [ [xLeft,yTop], [xLeft,yBottom], [xRight,yBottom], [xRight,yTop] ]; // set coords for selection, counter-clockwise

    selec.deselect;
    selec.select(newRect);

    // end
}
```